# AppEngine's urlfetch, how to force timeout to be respected

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch

I'm using Urlfetch from Google Appengine, and I add the deadline parameter to force the deadline to be short (3 seconds), like the following :

```
try:
    urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(3)
    return urlfetch.fetch(url='http://www.example.com', method=urlfetch.GET, deadline=3)
except google.appengine.runtime.apiproxy_errors.DeadlineExceededError:
    pass
except google.appengine.api.urlfetch_errors.DeadlineExceededError:
    pass

return None
```

But no matter what, my thread goes on and on for 60 seconds (the max execution time for an http request on Appengine) and then fail miserably on a DeadlineException ("Thread running after request.").

Is there a way to ensure that the upper query will be strictly stopped in 3 seconds?

Comment: Are you certain the exception isn't actually raised but caught and ignored by your code? Maybe try replacing the `pass` statements with some `logging` calls to check?

Comment: I believe the `set_default_fetch_deadline()` is for when you use `rpc` and `urlfetch.make_fetch_call()`.  Your `urlfetch.fetch(...deadline=3)` should suffice.  Try adding a generic `except:` and log inside that as well as the other `excepts`

Comment: No apparently the deadline parameter has been completely removed and now it's required to use the `set_default_fetch_deadline`. See the docs : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests?csw=1

Comment: I've replaced the "pass" with logging.exception('{the name of the exception}') and I'm getting the `google.appengine.api.urlfetch_errors.DeadlineExceededError` one. But the odd part is that apparently, the code gets stuck here, like if the logging.exception was raising an exception after 600 seconds (on a queue). That's not that at all!

Comment: I've advanced a bit more but still stuck with this. I discovered that the exception is first raised after 3 seconds (my deadline) and then the code hangs on the logging.info I've added until it reaches out it's max limit (of 600 s in my case). Why? I don't know!

Comment: Are you certain you're not returning from this function (via `return None`)? What's the caller of this function doing?

Comment: @DanCornilescu I'm not sure to understand. Of course I do a return when the exception occurs. I tried to `return None` and to return an empty object too, but the issue is always here.

Comment: Ok I've found the culprit ... It was Sentry. When a network requests was made and failled, I suspect it was Google's that had an network issue and so when Sentry got the error and tried to send the info to their server, the issue was still on. So it was Sentry, using `logging` that was blocking the request! I've removed it and now my app works well and stop correctly after the deadline.

Comment: Just to clarify a misstatement above... The `deadline` param has not been removed from `r=urlfetch.fetch()`.  It is still there, and will override any value set by `set_default_fetch_deadline()`.  Here is the function:  `def fetch(url, payload=None, method=GET, headers={},
          allow_truncated=False, follow_redirects=True,
          deadline=None, validate_certificate=None):`

Comment: Yes @GAEfan, my bad, I read later that it was still there. (It's another SO answer from the other question that was mentioning it has been removed).

Answer (score 1):

I can share some code I currently have running in one of my production projects. I use a deadline of 0.5 seconds in this example. Last I checked, it's still working:

```
t_rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc(deadline=0.5)
urlfetch.make_fetch_call(t_rpc, url)
# and then later...
try:
    result = t_rpc.get_result()
except:
    # handle errors...
    pass

# use the result...
```

This is actually using the asynchronous version of the API so you can technically do things in between calling `make_fetch_call` and `get_result`. Otherwise, you can just call them back-to-back and it will function the same as a synchronous API.

Comment: Thank you for the code, I'll try it. I was planning on using the asynchronous method to call urls I don't mind getting the result. Do you think it's ok if I never call the `rpc.get_result()`? Or this will results in some memory leak ?

Comment: Your code works great, and my original code too. The issue was with Sentry, a service to track errors, which was causing the issue!